# Function which no longer exists

Tags: matlab, function, undefined

I am interested in using the function here:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/removerows.html
However, when I try to use it in Matlab it says: `"Undefined function or variable 'removerows'"`
I typed: `exist removerows` and returned a value of 0, suggesting that it's been removed. Has this function just been renamed? or is it part of a toolbox I may not have, the information does not detail this.

Much appreciated

Comment: I find it in R2015a, maybe there is a problem with your path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the link that you posted, this function is part of the Neural Network Toolbox. So my guess is that you don't have this toolbox installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove rows in a matrix by assigning an empty array to them.
This way you don't have to use functions belonging to toolboxes that require extra licences.

Example

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]

A =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6

A(2,:) = []     %remove row 2

A =

     1     2
     5     6
```

Similarly you can provide an index array with the rows to be deleted in case you want to remove several ones.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, which may benefit others, but I am able to install other toolboxes as well.